# Grails Unable to create initial connections of pool

Tags: mysql, grails

When I run my Grails app and I get the following error

```
| Loading Grails 2.3.5
| Configuring classpath
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development
| Environment set to development.
| Environment set to development..
| Environment set to development...
| Environment set to development....
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application
| Packaging Grails application.
| Packaging Grails application..
| Packaging Grails application...
| Packaging Grails application....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 1 source files
| Compiling 1 source files.
| Compiling 1 source files..
| Compiling 1 source files...
| Compiling 1 source files....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Running Grails application
| Error 2015-04-21 11:54:24,947 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool    .
Message: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    Line | Method
->>  411 | handleNewInstance             in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1121 | createCommunicationsException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|    676 | readPacket . . . . . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   1088 | doHandshake                   in     ''
|   2493 | coreConnect . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2526 | connectOneTryOnly             in     ''
|   2311 | createNewIO . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    834 | <init>                        in     ''
|     47 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance             in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    416 | getInstance . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    347 | connect                       in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    262 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker                     in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                           in java.lang.Thread
Caused by EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpecte    dly>
>->> 3166 | readFully                     in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -     - - - - - >|    600 | readPacket                    in     ''
|   1088 | doHandshake . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|   2493 | coreConnect                   in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2526 | connectOneTryOnly . . . . . . in     ''
|   2311 | createNewIO                   in     ''
|    834 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     47 | <init>                        in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    416 | getInstance                   in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    347 | connect . . . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    262 | run                           in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2015-04-21 11:54:25,051 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool    .
Message: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    Line | Method
->>  411 | handleNewInstance             in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1121 | createCommunicationsException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|    676 | readPacket . . . . . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   1088 | doHandshake                   in     ''
|   2493 | coreConnect . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2526 | connectOneTryOnly             in     ''
|   2311 | createNewIO . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    834 | <init>                        in     ''
|     47 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance             in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    416 | getInstance . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    347 | connect                       in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    262 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker                     in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                           in java.lang.Thread
Caused by EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpecte    dly>
>->> 3166 | readFully                     in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -     - - - - - >|    600 | readPacket                    in     ''
|   1088 | doHandshake . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|   2493 | coreConnect                   in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2526 | connectOneTryOnly . . . . . . in     ''
|   2311 | createNewIO                   in     ''
|    834 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     47 | <init>                        in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    416 | getInstance                   in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    347 | connect . . . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    262 | run                           in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2015-04-21 11:54:25,139 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool    .
Message: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    Line | Method
->>  411 | handleNewInstance             in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1121 | createCommunicationsException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|    676 | readPacket . . . . . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   1088 | doHandshake                   in     ''
|   2493 | coreConnect . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2526 | connectOneTryOnly             in     ''
|   2311 | createNewIO . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    834 | <init>                        in     ''
|     47 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance             in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    416 | getInstance . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    347 | connect                       in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    262 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker                     in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                           in java.lang.Thread
Caused by EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpecte    dly>
>->> 3166 | readFully                     in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -     - - - - - >|    600 | readPacket                    in     ''
|   1088 | doHandshake . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|   2493 | coreConnect                   in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2526 | connectOneTryOnly . . . . . . in     ''
|   2311 | createNewIO                   in     ''
|    834 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     47 | <init>                        in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    416 | getInstance                   in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    347 | connect . . . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    262 | run                           in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2015-04-21 11:54:25,169 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application:     Err>
>The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.    >Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org    .spr
>The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.    >    Line | Method>->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFac    tor>
>The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.    >->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDete    cto>
>The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.    >->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exc    ept>
>The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.    >->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.C    omm>
>The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.    >->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
->>  411 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1121 | createCommunicationsException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|    676 | readPacket in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   1088 | doHandshake in     ''
|   2493 | coreConnect in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2526 | connectOneTryOnly in     ''
|   2311 | createNewIO in     ''
|    834 | <init>    in     ''
|     47 | <init> .  in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    416 | getInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    347 | connect   in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    262 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpecte    dly>
>->> 3166 | readFully in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    600 | readPacket in     ''
|   1088 | doHandshake in     ''
|   2493 | coreConnect in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2526 | connectOneTryOnly in     ''
|   2311 | createNewIO in     ''
|    834 | <init> .  in     ''
|     47 | <init>    in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    416 | getInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    347 | connect . in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/TestDebug
```

and my code is the following:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/nuage_v3"
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
            username = "root"
            password = "root"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=false
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
               jdbcInterceptors="ConnectionState"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The user and password are both correct, I tried reinstalling MySQL.

Comment: Is MySQL connector is present in BuildConfig.groovy?If yes then put `url` as `url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but alas that did not fix my problem

Comment: Of course the driver is present - read the stack trace. Your url won't do anything here - all you're doing is adding in the port which can be omitted when it's the default, and `?autoReconnect=true` but reconnecting isn't the problem - connecting is.

Comment: Can you connect to that server from another client using the same settings?

Comment: I can connect to it via mysql with bash no problem.
The server itself is local so I can't use another client.

Comment: Have you try  by changing the localhost to ip i.e 127.0.0.1, I faced the issue  and I did that and issue was gone but I don't know why.

Comment: Just tried it, did not work.
Thanks anyway

Comment: @Spoony Please provide used grails version and mysql connector version in BuildConfig.groovy

Comment: @Spoony Please restart the mysql server and try it again.

Comment: @Spoony Have you created database 'nuage_v3' in the mysql server?

Answer (score 0):

I've given up on trying to solve the problem.
I reinstalled grails and mysql on a diffenrent machine and it seems to work.
sorry to have bothered you all.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is Mysql is not running.First run apache and Mysql then run grails app.Hope it will works .Also check 80 port is free or not if not then free your 80 port.

Answer (score -1):

The same problem..  All of a sudden..
MySQLWorkbench works well, but grails "Unable to create initial connections of pool"

I've been spend half a day trying to fix this, searching answers. But nothing work for me..